# How to organize and test code in functional style in Java

Tags: java, functional-programming

I have an OOP approach to calculating a special code. There is a list of strategies that uses the chain of responsibility approach to calculate my value;

```
interface ChainStrategy {
  Strategy getNext();
  String getCode(SomeDto dto); 
  default String getDefaultVlue() {
    return "";
  };
}

class StrategyA implements ChainStrategy {
  Strategy next;
  StrategyA() {}

  StrategyA(Strategy next) {
    this.next = next;
  }

  Strategy getNext() {
    return next;
  }
  public String getCode(SomeDto dto) {
    if(dto.isA()) {
      String result = dto.getA();
      //this code could be placed in the abstract class to fulfill DRY
      if(result == null) {
        if(next!=null) {
          result = next.getCode(dto);
        }
        else {
         result = getDefaultVlue();
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
  }
  
  class StrategyB implements ChainStrategy {
    // mostly the same code with different result calculation logic 
  }

  class Client {
     ChainStrategy strategy = new StrategyA(new StrategyB());
     System.out.println(strategy.getCode())
  }
}
```

This is "Java < 8" code that meets SOLID principles and can be easily tested. Usually, the real logic is more complicated than just `dto.getA()`

But it is just a chain of functions so I rewrite it:

```
interface ChainStrategy {
  String getCode(SomeDto dto); 
}

class CombineStrategy implements ChainStrategy {

  private static final Function<SomeDto, Optional<String>> STRATEGY_A = dto -> Optional.of(dto).filter(SomeDto::isA).map(SomeDto::getA());

  private static final Function<SomeDto, Optional<String>> STRATEGY_B = dto -> Optional.of(dto).filter(SomeDto::isB).map(SomeDto::getB());

  private static final Function<SomeDto, String> STRATEGY_DEFAULT = dto -> "";

  String getCode(SomeDto dto) {
   Stream.of(STRATEGY_A, STRATEGY_B).map(st->st.apply(dto))
                                    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                                    .map(Optional::get)
                                    .findFirst()
                                    .orElseGet(() -> STRATEGY_DEFAULT.apply(dto));
  }

}
```

And my questions:

1. This code has problems with a single responsibility and "open-close" principles. And I can't test my functions individually. But creating separate classes for my functions looks like an overhead. Do we need these principles in functional programming?
2. I can rewrite "String getCode" to another static function. And store all these functions as a static Util class. But I don't want to lose ability to dynamically substitute my ChainFunction in the runtime. How do people combine static functions and dynamic binding in functional languages?

Comment: FWIW, you can view the [Chain of Responsibility pattern as a sequence of catamorphisms](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/07/22/chain-of-responsibility-as-catamorphisms).

Comment: just a remark about your second code-block: I guess you have typos in all the method references which should be without the brackets, i.e. `SomeDto::isA` instead of `SomeDto::isA()` and same for the others. Further, for the Code to compile, `getCode()` needs to be public and is missing the `return`. Ah, and 'dto' stands for data transfer object, I guess? I don't (yet) have any helpful remark adressing the actual question.

Comment: concerning the testability only: why did you make the strategy members private? In the OOP approach they weren't private classes, so why should they be private members now?